# BrowserStack Selenium timeout exceeded, flaky tests

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, browserstack

Everytime my BrowserStack Selenium (NodeJS) tests run, I see randomly tests are failing with an »timeout exceeded« error. One time it's 5 scripts, the next time 10 scripts, then again only 2 scripts. My test suite is flaky and not at all stable.

**Here is an example of a randomly failing test script:**

```
describe('test scripts', function () {
    var driver;
    ...

    afterEach(async function() {
        await driver.quit();
    });

    it('xx', async function () {
        driver.executeScript(...);

        try {
            await driver.get(...);
            await await driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementLocated(By.xpath(el)), 20000).click();
            await driver.executeScript(...);

        } catch (e) {
            await driver.executeScript(...);
            throw e;
        }
    });
});
```

I know it's about some missing explicit or implicit waiting command.

- So, I did try `await driver.manage().setTimeouts( { implicit: 5000 } );` after the `await driver.get(...);`.
- I also tried to rewrite the click-functionality to include some waiting like this: `await driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementLocated(By.xpath(el)), 20000, 'Timed out after 20 seconds', 4000).then(el => el.click())`
- In the capabilities, I also included `'browserstack.idleTimeout': '300'`

I tried all tips from this article:
https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/troubleshooting/browserstack-idle-timeout#issue

Answer (score 0):

I suggest going thru BS documentation:

- https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/troubleshooting/browserstack-idle-timeout#issue
- https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/error-codes/browserstack-idle-timeout#why-you-must-mitigate-this-issue

If that doesn't help, try to reach out to BS Support.

Comment: No, I have tried that.